# Tricks for calculating absolute third moment?

Tags: probability-theory

Are there any useful tricks for calculating third absoute moments, similar to MGFs for raw and central moments? In particular, I'd like the third absolute moment of the Lognormal, normal, weibull, and binomial (discrete version). I can't seem to find much on the web or in my textbooks about the $\textit{absolute}$ third moment $\gamma$.

Where $\gamma = \int |X|^3 dF $

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Could you write down the definition of "absolute third moment"? This would improve readability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the easiest method to obtain the answers is to use a computer algebra system to do the grunt work for you. Here is a quick session with the `mathStatica` add-on to *Mathematica* ... took less than a minute to derive all of them:

[image]

(I should add that I am one of the authors of mathStatica.)

**As for tricks:** 
For the Lognormal, Binomial and the Weibull, the domain of support is positive, so the absolute third moment will be identical to the third moment (so you should be able to find these in a book). For the case of a Normal, the absolute third moment of a general Normal random variable will be the same as the third moment of a folded Normal random variable ... and one might be able to find that result in a book too.

Comment: Wolfies - many thanks. This was extremely helpful :)